# How to remove unix timestamp specific data from a flatfile

Tags: awk, sed, grep, timestamp

I have a huge file containing a list like this

```
email@domain.com^B1569521698
email2@domain.com,@2domain.com^B1569521798
email3@domain.com,test@2domain.com^B1569521898
email10000@domain.com^B1569521998
..
..
```

The file is named /usr/local/email/whitelist

The number after ^B is a unix timestamp

I need to remove from the list all the rows having a timestamp smaller than 
(e.g.) 1569521898.

I tried using various awk/sed combinations with no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have control characters in your Input_file could you please try following once. This is written and tested with given samples only.

```
awk '
match($0,/\002[0-9]+/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)
  if(val>=1569521898){ print }
  val=""
}
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 5):

The character `^B` you notice is a [control character](http://ascii-table.com/control-chars.php). The first 32 control-characters which are ASCII codes `0` through `1FH`, form a special set of non-printing characters. These characters are called the control characters because these characters perform various printer and display control operations rather than displaying symbols. This particular one stands for `STX` or `Start of Text`.

You can type control-charcters in a shell as: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>, or you can use the octal representation directly (`\002`).

```
awk -F '\002' '($2 >= 1569521898)'
```